# How to get error message for user from facebook exception android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-exception

I have created a project with login facebook function.

When testing in offline mode, I recieve a FacebookException in method `onError(FacebookException error)`. error.getMessage()`I get this String`"net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"`.

But the thing I want is an error message for user such as "Fail Connection" or something else like that.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll have to implement your own logic to switch based on error type and choose an appropriate string. Exception messages are rarely (if ever) translated into locales other than English so it's never appropriate to pipe them directly to the UI.

Comment: got it. thanks so much :))))